# Please don't remove questions from the reopen queue when there is debate about the original close reason

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, moderation, vote-to-close

Background:

1. Questions can be closed when 5 members (with enough reputation) think it is off topic or otherwise problematic.
2. Closed questions can be reopened when 5 members (with enough reputation) think it is fine.
3. Questions that are edited can be added to the 'reopen' review queue to see if they should be reopened.
4. A moderator's vote is decisive:

   - When a moderator chooses to vote/reopen, this is done immediately.
   - When a moderator handles a question in review and chooses to **not** vote/reopen, the question is **removed from the review queue**.

My understanding is that (1) and (2) are a crude way of implementing a majority vote. (4) is a shortcut for obvious cases. (3) is independent, it just makes sure we don't miss things.

Recently I have seen a couple of cases where:

- A question was closed through a moderator vote (4a).
- There was debate in the comments whether the question should be closed at all.
- The users who thought the question should not be closed voted to reopen (2).
- The same moderator then removed the question from the reopen queue (4b).

Examples: [intransitive form of *obtain*](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/posts/43082/revisions) (also discussed [here](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2013/17305)); [subject Wh-questions](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/posts/43206/revisions); [Greek zōē and bios](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/posts/16790/revisions); [rock paper scissors](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/posts/43278/revisions); [What would /ɯ/ most likely be replaced by?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/43774/17305).

All these were left closed in review because "original close reason(s) were not resolved". But this does not make sense, because it was in the reopen queue **because people felt the original close reason was incorrect**: there was, according to them, nothing to be resolved in the first place. In my view, removing the question from the review queue (4b) hinders the majority vote mechanism described above, because like this not enough people get to see the question in the reopen review process.

Therefore my simple request: if as a moderator you have previously voted to close/reopen a question and this is debated, please don't reuse your moderator vote and let the normal process take place; just skip the question in review. I am aware that most moderators already do this; thank you!

Comment: At least the rock, paper, scissors still appears to be in the queue https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/30413

Comment: @VladimirF yes, thanks for that—I was not entirely clear. I made a minor edit to put it back in the queue. You can see the timeline [here](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/posts/43278/revisions).